# d3 geojson creating path: Select index of coordinates

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson, mercator

I'm trying to draw a path(track) on a d3 geojson map by selecting always 2 Coordinates of my data called track.json. Here's part of this data:

```
{"id":"B", "hour":18, "lat":50.900999, "lon":4.485574, "class": 2},
{"id":"C", "hour":12, "lat":13.775091, "lon":100.622656, "class": 2},
{"id":"D", "hour":12, "lat":35.771987, "lon":140.39285, "class": 2},
```

Now I'm trying to get the coordinates and build a path on my map(it's the track of a world-traveler) which works actually, by getting all the coordinates at once:

```
  var pathLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("polygon")
    .x(function(d) { return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]; });
```

But I want the path to be displayed one by one by clicking a button.

```
document.getElementById("myLink").onclick = function(){
var pathLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("polygon")
    .x(function(d) { return projection([d[0].lon, d[0].lat])[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return projection([d[1].lon, d[1].lat])[1]; });
```

I know that this isn't possible because with function(d) I'm getting all the coordinates at once. It should be something like track[0].lon. I already tried to replace "track" instead(track is the name of the datasource) of "d" but this doesn't work neither...

Comment: Why not create pathes and setting them all invisible, and then just show them via JQuery via runtime? Much easier =)